# Physical Workstation/Computer joining a domain

Tags: windows

I am trying out to be an IT sysadmin.

I managed to install Windows Server 2012 on my VM and AD. I have set up my domain, user accounts, joining workstation to the AD (by creating another VM), and everything.

I am just curious if it is possible for a physical computer that is outside the VM to join my domain (that is set up in Windows Server 2012 in the VM)

It would be interesting if that works out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Unfortunately, you have not provided information about what VM software you are using, so I cannot tell you how to do it exactly, only what you need to change.

Whenever you use a VM, the guest is shielded off from the main network in a virtual network behind a NAT. In most VM solutions you can either open ports specifically to allow traffic to go through, or alter the network card from NAT to bridged, which essentially places your VM inside your network, giving it full access to the network, and also allowing the entire network to see your server.

You need to set the network card to bridged.

Keep in mind, that for AD, you often also install a DHCP server. Once the server resides inside your network, the DHCP server of the server is now also part of your network, giving 2 DHCP servers. You will want to disable one of the two.

Another problem is going to be the DNS server. Your AD server will be required to use DNS or you cannot domain join the server. So on the DHCP server that is still active, you will have to setup the DNS Server to be your AD Server. The AD Server then can be set to use the router's DNS server, and have both in effect.

Once all is correct, you should be able to join your domain by its FQDN, for example: domain.local, not to be mistaken by DOMAIN.